# is it ever appropriate to wear a gold lamé kittel?

Tags: minhag, kittel

Is it ever appropriate to wear a gold lamé kittel?  As far as I know, there were no holidays this weekend (Sept. 9 - 10), but I spotted someone in a pale gold lamé kittel that would have looked more appropriate in Las Vegas than Forest Hills, but what do I know?  is there some kind of minhag for when it's appropriate and when not?

Comment: Miriam Pratt, welcome to Mi Yodeya. Perhaps what you saw was a [Yerushalmi bekishe](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c9/Jewish_Orthodox_dress_code3.jpg/300px-Jewish_Orthodox_dress_code3.jpg)?

Comment: @ezra, I've never seen those outside of E"Y, except in Purim photos

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - Me neither but that sounds like what it was!

Comment: @danny schoemann, it looked more like photo of the Purim costume on the child than an actual bekishe (which is considerably longer than the one I saw).   More than likely, it originated in Israel -- I've never seen one here before!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're referring to men.

It's customary to wear a **white** Kittel all night and day on Yom Kippur - source [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 131](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0130_L2)

> נוֹהֲגִין לִלְבּוֹשׁ אֶת הַקִּיטֶל, שֶׁהוּא בֶּגֶד מֵתִים, וְעַל יְדֵי זֶה לֵב הָאָדָם נִכְנָע וְנִשְׁבָּר. ‏

Some also do so on Rosh Hashana during the day. (And some wear it all day on Rosh Hashana too)

On Shabbat Chazon some have the custom not wear their regular Shabbat clothes - ([ibid 122](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0121_L2))

> אֲבָל שְׁאָר בִּגְדֵי שַׁבָּת, תַּלְיָא בְּמִנְהַג הַמְּקוֹמוֹת אִם לְהַחְלִיפָן אוֹ לֹא

Any other week one is supposed to **get dressed in nice clothes for Shabbat** ([ibid 72](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0071_L2)). A gold lamé kittel would surely qualify.

> יִשְׁתַּדֵּל שֶׁיִּהְיוּ לוֹ בְּגָדִים נָאִים, וְגַם טַלִּית שֶׁל מִצְוָה נָאָה לִכְבוֹד שַׁבָּת, דִּכְתִיב וְכִבַּדְתּוֹ, וְדָרְשִׁינָן, שֶׁלֹּא יְהֵא מַלְבּוּשְׁךָ שֶׁל שַׁבָּת כְּמַלְבּוּשְׁךָ שֶׁל חֹל ‏

BTW:

- Classic Yerushalmi dress code is a golden striped knee-length coat. [image: golden striped knee-length coat]
- Some Rebbes wear very colorful robes on Shabbat. [image: Rebbe wearing colorful robes][image: Rebbe wearing colorful robes][image: Rebbe wearing colorful robes]
- The Sefardi Chief Rabbis wear a silver/gold & black robe. [image: Sefardi Chief Rabbi][image: Sefardi Chief Rabbi]